# Error in Fedora 34 after adding repo

Tags: linux-kernel, repository

I was adding the repo for Albert launcher , but then there was a Rawhide version of it and Fedora 34 IS Rawhide. I had added the Fedora 33 repo but then searched online ad disabled it by using "--set-disabled" instead of --add-repo. After I added the repos, I update. Then this error came:

```
Problem 1: package kernel-modules-extra-5.12.5-300.fc34.x86_64 requires kernel-uname-r = 5.12.5-300.fc34.x86_64, but none of the providers can be installed
```

- conflicting requests
  Problem 2: package kernel-5.12.5-300.fc34.x86_64 requires kernel-core-uname-r = 5.12.5-300.fc34.x86_64, but none of the providers can be installed
- conflicting requests
  I don't really think it's the adding repo error. I hadn't updated for about a week.

Comment: Fedora 34 isn’t Rawhide...

Comment: Suggest: **1**. Delete the alien repo's from /etc/yum/repos.d/ ... **2**. Download albert-0.17.2 https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home%3A/manuelschneid3r/Fedora_Rawhide/x86_64/albert-0.17.2-281.21.x86_64.rpm ... ... and install `# dnf install Downloads/albert-0.17.2-281.21.x86_64.rpm` ..... ~Two dependencies will also be installed.

Comment: The problem still persists

Comment: The "kernel-5.12.5-300.fc34" issue ? ? ......... I also made a weekly package update, and got the three kernel packages installed : **5.12.8-300.fc34** , i.e. not 5.12.5 !

Comment: ya the kernel issue